# How to use i18next in serverless node js?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, azure-functions, serverless

I am using Node JS Azure functions. I am trying to internationalize the error messages returned by the functions with i18next. I could find examples with express or plain node server. In these cases middleware pattern can be used.

But for functions, I need a way to call i18next.t('key') with probably a language parameter which I am not able to find. Calling i18next.changeLanguage() before every call to i18next.t('key') doesn't seem practical.

My skeleton code is as follows

```
const i18next = require("i18next");
const backend = require("i18next-node-fs-backend");

const options = {
    // path where resources get loaded from
    loadPath: '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    // path to post missing resources
    addPath: '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json',
    // jsonIndent to use when storing json files
    jsonIndent: 4
};

i18next.use(backend).init(options);

exports.getString = (key, lang) => {
   //i18next.changeLanguage(lang,
   return i18next.t(key);
}
```

It is possible to fetch translations without doing changeLanguage each time?

Comment: Trying to better understand the scenario, shouldn't changeLanguage be called everytime depending on where the call is coming from? Assuming you are using a HttpTrigger Azure Function and taking lang as an input to the trigger as a query string parameter

Comment: Yes, that's correct understanding. Based on debug logs, it seems to load messages whenever changeLanguage() is called. It seems like a time consuming method. Calling it repeatedly can slow down the API. Let me know if this understanding is correct.

Comment: If language needs to be detected on every invocation, you need to call changeLanguage. If lang is already known value and does not have to change, then you can default to a language [i18next.com configuration-options](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that changeLanguage() is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you need to call the `i18next.changeLanguage(lang)` function whenever the language needs to be defined or changed.

You can take a look to the [documentation here](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage).

The code could look like this

```
const i18next = require('i18next')
const backend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend')

const options = {
    // path where resources get loaded from
    loadPath: '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    // path to post missing resources
    addPath: '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json',
    // jsonIndent to use when storing json files
    jsonIndent: 4
}

i18next.use(backend).init(options)

exports.getString = (key, lang) => {
    return i18next
        .changeLanguage(lang)
        .then((t) => {
            t(key) // -> same as i18next.t
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the getFixedT function.
And not use the deprecated i18next-node-fs-backend, but i18next-fs-backend instead.

```
import { dirname, join } from 'path'
import { readdirSync, lstatSync } from 'fs'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import i18next from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-fs-backend'

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const localesFolder = join(__dirname, './locales')

i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .init({
    // debug: true,
    initImmediate: false, // setting initImediate to false, will load the resources synchronously
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    preload: readdirSync(localesFolder).filter((fileName) => {
      const joinedPath = join(localesFolder, fileName)
      return lstatSync(joinedPath).isDirectory()
    }),
    ns: 'news-mailer',
    backend: {
      loadPath: join(localesFolder, '{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json')
    }
  })

export default (lng) => i18next.getFixedT(lng)
```

Read more about it here: https://locize.com/blog/i18n-serverless/